# How to custom URL in browser when React app starting？

Tags: reactjs

[default url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8jzJ.png)

[opend url in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zprg.png)

I need to use my custom URL, such as：https://www.test.com:3000/recipe-app

Comment: Change your hosts file to route that domain to the ip.

Comment: The localhost URL will get replaced in production with whatever domain you have. Why do you want it in development?

Comment: Because when I fetch data, I need send some cookie to server. The cookie include my token.

Comment: You have to set up a server and link your  domain tonthat server then you can have your own custom url.